# How can I add to bookmarks without using section or chapter?

Tags: bookmarks

This is what I'm trying to fix on bookmarks, I want to add the TEST on my bookmarks and under the TEST I want to add LOREM

> TEST
> >LOREM

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \title{DotFill}
    \author{jasond.worked }
    \date{September 2022}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \textbf{TEST} \newline
    
    \noindent\textbf{LOREM}\\
    \indent\lipsum[]
        
    \end{document}
```

Comment: see the bookmark package.

Answer (score 1):

With the package `bookmark` you can use the command `\pdfbookmark[level]{text}{name}` to add a manual link.

`name` is used for
the internal anchor name   in conjunction with `level`. Therefore the name must be unique.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{DotFill}
\author{jasond.worked }
\date{September 2022}

\begin{document}    

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \pdfbookmark[subsection]{TEST}{test}
    \textbf{TEST}
     \newline
     
    \pdfbookmark[subsection]{LOREM}{lorem}
    \noindent\textbf{LOREM}
    
    \indent\lipsum[]
    
\end{document}
```

**Comment** The command `\pdfbookmark` can also be used loading the package `hyperref`.  However this is a hint found in the `hyperref`   manual (both packages share the same author):

> Package `bookmark` replaces `hyperref`’s bookmark organization by a
> new algorithm:
>
> • Usually only one LATEX run is needed.
>
> • More control over the bookmark appearance (color, font).
>
> • Different bookmark actions are supported.
>
> Therefore I recommend using this package